# How to return ArrayList<Boolean> in JNI java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm new to JNI and I want to create an `ArrayList<Boolean>` from the C++ side.

I have the following situation:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class createArrayJNI {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("libnative");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createArrayJNI jni =  new createArrayJNI();
        ArrayList<Boolean> array = jni.creatArray();
        System.err.println(array);
    }

    public native ArrayList<Boolean> creatArray();
}
```

and my cpp file is:

```cpp
...
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_createArrayJNI_creatArray
(JNIEnv \*env, jobject thisObject) {

    jclass java_util_class = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
        jmethodID java_util_method_constructor = env->GetMethodID(java_util_class, "<init>", "()V");
        jmethodID java_add_method = env->GetMethodID(java_util_class, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
        jobject java_util_object = env->NewObject(java_util_class, java_util_method_constructor, "");
        jboolean a = true;
         env->CallBooleanMethod(java_util_object, java_add_method, a);
    
         return java_util_object;
}
```

It shows me:

```
# 
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
# 
# SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001099110ac, pid=24207, tid=4355
# 
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (19.0.1) (build 19.0.1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (19.0.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  \[libjvm.dylib+0x1f10ac\]  AccessInternal::PostRuntimeDispatch\<G1BarrierSet::AccessBarrier\<598116ull, G1BarrierSet\>, (AccessInternal::BarrierType)2, 598116ull\>::oop_access_barrier(void\*)+0xc
# 
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
# 
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/taki/Desktop/Preparation doctorat ERM/Projects/Julia4C/hs_err_pid24207.log
# 
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues
# 
zsh: abort      /usr/bin/env  --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp
```

I'm pretty sure that the error comes from `env->CallBooleanMethod(java_util_object, java_add_method, a);` because the add method requires an object, and `a` is jboolean.

I tried to cast the `a` variable but it didn't work as well.

Comment: `\*env` ? typo?

Comment: Just made a mistake when asking the question in my code it is correct thank you!

Comment: a fatal error, a SIGSEGV in the software you are using is a bug in the software you are using. The message even suggests you to file a bug report. The message also suggests how to get more information by turning on core dumps, did you try that?

Comment: You can't use a primitive `bool`/`jboolean`. You need to create/get an instance of `java.lang.Boolean`.

Comment: I think you need to pass `Boolean` object, not `jboolean` which is equvalent to plain `boolean` type and boxing don't work for JNI.  Also, you may be better off to return `boolean[]` and convert it to `ArrayList<Boolean>` on Java side, since there is JNI functions to work with arrays.

Comment: Also, why are you trying to pass an empty C string to the `ArrayList` constructor?

Comment: It created a log file which is not very helpful.
I tried the same example but to create an ArrayList of Strings and it works just I need to instanciate jstring is this way  jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("test"); i want a function that do the same for the Boolean

Comment: There is none. You'll have to write such a function yourself.

Comment: @Michael empty string because i dont have arguments to pass to the init function

Comment: If you don't have any arguments then you shouldn't pass anything. I.e. remove the `, ""`

Comment: I bet the crash was occuring because of the empty string and another crash would have occurred once it hit the unboxed boolean being passed to the add() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to instantiate a java Boolean Object from c++ using
`Boolean.valueOf()` function.
I first get staticMethodId and then use it to create `jobject` and use the same object in the add method as follow:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_createArrayJNI_creatArray
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObject) {
    std::vector<bool> cpp_vec;
    cpp_vec.push_back(true);
    cpp_vec.push_back(false);
    cpp_vec.push_back(true);
    
    jclass java_util_class = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");
    jmethodID java_util_method_constructor = env->GetMethodID(java_util_class, "<init>", "()V");
    jmethodID java_add_method = env->GetMethodID(java_util_class, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
    
    jobject java_util_object = env->NewObject(java_util_class, java_util_method_constructor, "");
    
    jclass bool_class = env->FindClass("java/lang/Boolean");
    jmethodID bool_init = env->GetStaticMethodID(bool_class, "valueOf", "(Z)Ljava/lang/Boolean;");
    
    for (int i=0; i< cpp_vec.size(); i++){
      jboolean curr_element = cpp_vec[i];
      jobject bool_object = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(bool_class, bool_init, (jboolean) cpp_vec[i]);
      if (bool_object == NULL){
        std::cout << "Cannot instantiate the Boolean object";
        return NULL;
      } 
      env->CallBooleanMethod(java_util_object, java_add_method, bool_object);
    }
    return java_util_object;
}
```

Comment: You can get `Boolean` for `true` and `false` just once and then add them to array. And you can simplify you JNI function significantly by returning `Boolean[]` array from JNI and then do `ArrayList<Boolean> array = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jni.createArray()));`

Comment: It can perfectly work, but my situation is more complicated than this. basically I'm willing to create a mapper between c++ objects and java objects and my java objects have several arrayList fields. and I want to do all the processing in c++ side. Now everything is solved Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<Boolean>` is the same as just `ArrayList`. At runtime, the `<Boolean>` doesn't exist. This is called "type erasure".

The next thing to notice is that you did not try to add a `Boolean` (a kind of `Object`) but a primitive `boolean`. This probably gets interpreted as an object pointer and since it's not null it's the address of an `Object` - but `true` (the number 1) isn't a valid address of anything, and when the JVM dereferences it it crashes.

You need to get the static field `Boolean.TRUE` and add that to the `ArrayList`.